# How to fix Sonar issue for Private constructor?

Tags: java, sonarqube, inject

I have a Private constructor for an Implement class and I hope this class can only be created from injector. However, in Sonar it gives a Major issue: Private constructor 'XXX' is never used.

What's the suitable way to fix this kind of Sonar issue?

The language is JAVA. The plugin is sonarqube 5.3.

The example code is like:

```
@Inject
private DomainTableDaoImpl(GoldCopyDataSourceProvider gcDSProvider) {
    dataSource = gcDSProvider.getDataSource();
}
```

Comment: what is the language? what is the plugin version? can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a public factory method for this purpose and use this method for getting instance and inject it in another class instance.